# GUID to string filepath

Tags: c#, string, filesystems, converters, guid

I'm trying to parse a GUID which represents the filepath of folders inside the MusicLibrary.

Here's what the GUID code looks like directly from the libraryfile:

```
knownfolder: {4BD8D571-6D19-48D3-BE97-422220080E43}
```

If I paste the whole string into my explorer bar, it opens my Music folder just fine.

But how do I convert this to ex. D:\Music in C# code?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask you all.

Thanks in advance and happy holidays :)

Comment: You can pinvoke [SHGetKnownFolderPath()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetKnownFolderPath.html), its 1st argument is that guid.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum.

```
var music = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
```

Comment: If you have more than one folder in your library, it will only give me one if I'm not mistaking. That's why I use this method.

Comment: Ah. Came up with a solution. If I have more than one library folder in the library, it's only the first one that uses a GUID, which also is the same as environment.specialfolder.music. All the other folders within the library comes up as a normal searchpath. Thanks for the help :)